# Hive - Multiple clusters pointing to same metastore

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, metastore

We have two clusters say one as old and one as new. Both of them are on AWS - EMR. Hive on these clusters pointing to same Hive metastore, which is on RDS. We are migrating from old to new.

Now the question is if I stop old cluster will there be any issue for accessing old tables? " All the data is on S3. All tables are EXTERNAL. But still the databases are on HDFS.. like

```
hdfs://old:1234/user/hive/warehouse/myfirst.db
```

If I stop the old cluster this location be void which makes db invalid and also tables? Though they are external.

I am really not sure if this will be an issue but this is on prod so I am trying to find if anyone already faced this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as all your tables have the LOCATION set to S3, loosing the location for the DATABASE/SCHEMA will not impact access to your metadata.

The only impact it will have in your new cluster is that CREATE TABLE statements  performed in the custom database ("myfirstdb" in your example) without a explicit LOCATION will fail to reach the default HDFS path, which is inherited from the DATABASE location.

Tables created in the "default" schema will not fail as Hive will resolve the location for the new table to the value of the property "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", which is "/user/hive/warehouse" in Elastic MapReduce.

Again, this *does not* affect tables with an explicit LOCATION set at creation time.

In general, to achieve a completely "portable" Metastore what you will want to do is:

- Make sure all the TABLES have LOCATION set to S3 (any data in HDFS is obviously bound to the cluster lifecycle).
  This can be achieved by:

  - explicitely setting LOCATION in the CREATE TABLE statement or
  - setting LOCATION for all the DATABASE/SCHEMAS (other than 'default') to a path in S3
- Optionally (but strongly recommended) use EXTERNAL (user managed a.k.a. non-managed) tables to prevent accidental data loss due to DDL statements